# Explaining AIC Change When Removing/Adding Variables

Tags: model-selection, aic

I might be getting turned around in my thinking of AIC. My understanding, an example:

Let's say I have three models:
1.) AIC = 100, it has 10 variables
2.) AIC = 100, it has 9 variables
3.) AIC = 96, it has 11 variables

Simply looking at the AIC values, model 3 is the best; it is more than 2 AIC smaller that the others. To explain what's happening though:

AIC = 2k - 2ln(l)
2k = penalty for having more variables
ln(l) = benefit of explaining more of the data
thus, smaller AIC is better.

1.) Model we're comparing to.

2.) AIC is reduced because we lose some penalty (less variables -> smaller AIC); however, we also lose some explanation of the data (smaller log likelihood -> greater AIC). These changes canceled out, making the two models equivalent

3.) AIC is increased because we add some penalty (more variables -> greater AIC); however, our ability to explain the data (greater log-like -> smaller AIC) is better. The benefit to explain is greater than the detriment of more variables by enough (4 units more) that we want to include that variable.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I would remove the minus sign from *-ln(l) = benefit of explaining more of the data*, though, as greater log-likelihood corresponds to better explanation of the data.

Comment: This might be a typo but just in case it isn't: The formula for the AIC is *2k - 2ln(L)*.